# Excel: Dynamically change sheet tag based on cell value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to dynamically change the sheet tag name based on a cell value in another sheet, the "title" sheet. The dynamic change works well when I am doing the update from the same sheet and changes upon hitting enter after changing the cell value. But when the reference cell is located in another sheet, after hitting enter there is no change to the sheet tag until I actively access the sheet to be updated and click in the sheet. Is there anyway of getting around this? I have about 20 or so sheets so it would be laborious to click on each sheet when a change is made. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Set Target = Worksheet("Title").Range("A1")
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo Badname
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Target, 31)
    Exit Sub
Badname:
    MsgBox "Please revise the entry in A1." & Chr(13) _
    & "It appears to contain one or more " & Chr(13) _
    & "illegal characters." & Chr(13)
    Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

My other option is to add an update button to execute changes, but if possible I would like to avoid this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: because you code is scoped for a particular worksheet change. So if you have this code in Sheet1, only when you make change in sheet1 this code will come in play. Either add this code behind all the worksheets or just use the workbook level sheet change event `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` you can access it in the workbook object.

Comment: Did my solution work on your case?

Comment: @cyboashu, apologies for the late reply (went away). I've actually managed to get this working with a combination of both of the replies so thank you both for the input. The workbook_sheet change was the workbook level sheet change event that I was ultimately looking for so if you put that as an answer I will accept it. If it's not updated in a few days, I'll accept the current answer.  Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @RCaetano, please see the above comment. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @dl00065... awesome...

Comment: @cyboashu, please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested

because your code is scoped for a particular worksheet change. So if you have this code in Sheet1, only when you make change in sheet1 this code will come in play. Either add this code behind all the worksheets or just use the workbook level sheet change event Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range) you can access it in the workbook object.

Answer (score 0):

So you *have about 20 or so sheets so it would be laborious to click on each sheet when a change is made.* Why not to loop through all sheets to refresh the changes? :)

Something like:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sht In Worksheets
  sht.Activate
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

HTH ;)